# How to keep width/height ratio inside a LinearLayout?

Tags: android, layout, android-linearlayout, android-constraintlayout

I am trying to implement a layout like this:
[image]

I had added a code like below, but the problem is that the two ImageViews' heights is zero in the final rendered layout. I don't know why the `app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"` (height to width ratio 1:1) has no effect?   Did I missed something?

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:background="@drawable/orange_gradient"
    app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:0.5">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="10">

        <!-- want height to be constrained by 1:1 to width -->
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/croppedFaceImageView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="4"

            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"

            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/confidenceLabel"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="2"

            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="90%"

            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="8sp"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/avartarImageView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="4"

            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"

            android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_dark" />
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: `app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"` is for `ConstraintLayout`, not `LinearLayout`.

Comment: Will it work if I wrap the imageView inside a ConstraintLayout then?

Comment: You wouldn't wrap the ImageView in a ContraintLayout, you'd replace the LinearLayout with one.  Other alternatives include creating a custom view that in its onMeasure decides to scale its height relative to its width.

Answer (score 0):

You can only use app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio in a ConstraintLayout.
However, there is a way to achieve what you're looking for.

Replace the LinearLayout with ConstraintLayout and follow the following code template on your xml design
NB. Notice that the trick to have the child views line out properly is using constraint rules against each child.

```
        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/sun"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/mon"
                android:text="S"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/mon"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/sun"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/tue"
                android:text="M"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tue"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/mon"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/wed"
                android:text="T"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/wed"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/tue"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/thur"
                android:text="W"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/thur"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/wed"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/fri"
                android:text="T"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/fri"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/thur"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/sat"
                android:text="F"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/sat"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/fri"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                android:text="S"/>
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

The above code will create something like:
[image]